# easy way to convert windows paths with variables into python string

Tags: python

i tend to copy a lot of paths from a windows file explorer address bar, and they can get pretty long:

`C:\Users\avnav\Documents\Desktop\SITES\SERVERS\4. server1\0_SERVER_MAKER`

now let's say i want to replace `avnav` with `getpass.getuser()`.

if i try something like:

```
project_file = f'C:\Users\{getpass.getuser()}\Documents\Desktop\SITES\SERVERS\4. server1\0_SERVER_MAKER'
```

i will get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

i presume it's because of the single back slash - although would be cool to pinpoint exactly what part causes the error, because i'm not sure.

in any case, i can also do something like:

```
project_file = r'C:\Users\!!\Documents\Desktop\SITES\SERVERS\4. server1\0_SERVER_MAKER'.replace('!!', getpass.getuser())
```

but this becomes annoying once i have more variables.

so is there a solution to this? or do i have to find and replace slashes or something?

Comment: you're on windows laptop ? do double backslah or `rf'C:\...'`

Comment: What's wrong with using both `r` and `f`?

Comment: Use the Pathlib module.

Comment: @xbello i forgot to mention i tried pathlib, didn't seem to work - could you show the correct implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Error

---

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Read carefully. Yes, the error is that. There's a `U` char after a `\`.

This, in Python, is the way to insert in a string a `U`nicode character. So the interpreter expects `hex` digits to be after `\U`, but there's none so there's an exception raised.

## Replace

---

> so is there a solution to this? **or do i have to find and replace slashes** or something?

That **is a possible solution**, after replacing all `\` with `/` everything should be fine, but that's not the best solution.

## `Raw string`

---

Have you ever heard of **characters escaping**? In this case `\` is escaping `{`.

In order to prevent this, just put the path as a [`raw-string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-prefixes-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals).

```
rf'C:\Users\{getpass.getuser()}\Documents\Desktop\SITES\SERVERS\4. server1\0_SERVER_MAKER'
```

Comment: yea i was trying to avoid typing out double ```\```.  did not know about ```rf```!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made a piece of code to convert File Explorer file path into a python file format:

```
rawpath = input("PATH: ")
ds = "\\"

def CF(path):
    if ds in path:
        path = rawpath.replace("\\", "\\\"")
        rpath = repr(path).replace("\"", "")
        print(rpath)
        
CF(rawpath)
```